# Restore database from tape error 15105, cannot open backup device

Tags: sql-server, backup, restore

I'm using HP Data Protector software to backup my SQL databases. When i try to restore a database from tape i get the following error.

[image]

When i click on script, it says this:

```
RESTORE DATABASE [ICT_TEST] FROM  TAPE = N'Data Protector_STD2008_ICT_TEST_213007077_0' WITH  FILE = 1,  NORECOVERY,  NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10
GO
RESTORE LOG [ICT_TEST] FROM  DISK = N'E:\SQLbackup STD2008\ICT_TEST\ICT_TEST_backup_2015_02_27_224513_2053343.trn' WITH  FILE = 1,  NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10
GO
```

(I start SQL Management Studio as Domain Administrator)

Does anybody have a tip on how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the HP Data Protector console software to perform the restore operation.